# Pause Boostrap Carousel from console - wrong object

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble to pause a bootstrap 3 carousel. When I try to pause the carousel nothing is happening and it keeps on sliding. It seems like I'm setting pause on wrong object or something..

```
$('.carousel').carousel('pause');
```

When I run the command in console it seams like it trying to set the property on the correct selector (.carousel), see picture below:

[image: console picture]

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel mediaCarousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<div class="iterationNumbers">
    <div class="num"></div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-inner">

        .... each item ....

</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href=".carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href=".carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the carousel a unique ID, and select it by that:

```
$("#id_my_carousel").carousel('pause');
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/1430/) with a pause button at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause carousel while sliding, use this event to pause it after transtion:

```
$('#carouselId').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    $(this).carousel('pause');
});
```